# Possible to share WebMatrix-developed site through file system?

Tags: webmatrix

I've just finished creating a sample web site that I'd like to show to someone. I could publish it to a web server, but if possible I'd prefer to send it as a .zip file for the other person to view. My site utilizes WebMatrix's SQLite features, otherwise it would be a simple matter.

Is there some way I can share this web site as a .zip file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell the recipient to install WebMatrix, and when they receive your zip files, they should unzip it and then right click on the decompressed folder and choose Open as a Web Site with Microsoft WebMatrix, and then hit the Run button.